# JQuery to access Multi-Select Drop down menu

Tags: jquery

I am working on a multi-select drop-down menu mentioned below

```
<select class="form-input name="hideLineItemColumns_quote" multiple="true" ">
    <option selected="true" value="part_desc">Description</option>
    <option selected="true" value="part_number">Product</option>
    <option selected="true" value="costEa_line">Cost</option>
</select>
```

I want to access values & text of all selected options and use them in further logic. I tried doing this

```
var tempVar = jQuery("Select[@name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'] option:selected").text();
alert(tempVar[0]);
```

Instead of showing "Description", it shows "D". It combines all three values in one long string. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempVar` is a string. So you are looking at the first character in that string which is `D`

In addition, all you options are selected.

Perhaps this is what you meant to do:

```
var tempVar = [];
jQuery("Select[@name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'] option:selected").each(function () {
                  tempVar.push($(this).text());
});
alert(tempVar[0]);
```

Comment: Makes sense..but instead of returing a string, it should be returing an array with three values Description, Product & Cost. Is there any other way I can access all selected values, separately ?

Comment: Above code is working fine but there are other Select tags on the page and logic is pulling the first selected value of first Select tag instead of the one I specifically mentioned (@name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'). Do I need to specify something else?

Comment: yes, you are missing a closing `"` in this statement `<select class="form-input name="hideLineItemColumns_quote" multiple="true">` you need to `class="form-input"`

Comment: I fixed that, even then same issue. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/efh4a/2/

Comment: @Nitesh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1231/discussion-between-joe-tuskan-and-nitesh)

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is selecting all three `option` elements. When you call [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on this set, jQuery assumes you want the text of all three combined.

If you want to deal with them separately, you could iterate via [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) or [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
// with .each():
$("select[@name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'] option:selected").each(function(idx, el) {
    console.log($(el).text());
});

// with .map():
var options_arr = $("select[@name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'] option:selected").map(function(idx, el) {
    return $(el).text();
}); // => ['Description', 'Product', 'Cost']
console.log(options_arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hans/kCZDh/1/

Comment: Do you have any idea why its showing SS instead of Description in the alert message jsfiddle.net/efh4a/2?

Answer (score 0):

I've played with it a bit...

```
var tempVar = [];
$('select[name="hideLineItemColumns_quote"] option:selected').each(function() {
    var $option = $(this);
    tempVar.push({ text: $option.text(), value: $option.attr('value') });
});
alert(tempVar[0].text);
```

What it does basically, like one of the other answers, is make an array of the selected items of your list. For each selected items, it creates a tiny object that contains a `text` and `value` property so you can access them more intuitively later on. (Like in the `alert()` line);